# Overflow exception in C sharp while binding data for more than 20k records,

Tags: c#

i have already used 
httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="99898989"  targetFramework="4.5" on webconfig
but it did not work for more than 20k records binding on gridview.**Below errors mentioned below:**

***Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.***
**Exception Details:** System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.[ArgumentException: Error serializing value 'System.Data.DataSet' of type 'System.Data.DataSet.']
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value) +3499
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Stream outputStream, Object stateGraph) +144
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +71
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Serialize(Object state, Purpose purpose) +13
System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +40
 System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save() +106
System.Web.UI.Page.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(Object state) +108System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() +606
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            checkLogin();
            //Check User Login 

        }

    }

    public void checkLogin()
    {


       name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        DataSet ds = mrbrbal.getUserDetails(name.ToUpper().ToString());

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {


            else if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserType"].ToString().ToUpper() == "PROCESSOR")
            {
                bindAllMRBRReport();
                btnSubmitRejectByProcessor.Visible = true;//pop up reject
                btnResumeMail.Visible = true;
                btnHoldInvoices.Visible = true;
                btnRejectInvoice.Visible = false;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            bindAllMRBRReportByName(name);

            btnSubmitReject.Visible = true;//reject button
        }

    }`
```

public void bindAllMRBRReport()
        {

```
        ds = mrbrbal.getAllMRBRReport();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvMRBRReport.DataSource = ds;
            ViewState["Paging"] = ds;
            ViewState["Total"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            gvMRBRReport.DataBind();

        }


    }
```

`

Comment: We can do nothing with just an Exception. You'll need to add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @PeterB-Updated Code. Could you please help

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use paging for your gridview.20K is a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Error serializing value 'System.Data.DataSet' of type 'System.Data.DataSet` is caused by trying to save the `ds` object into `ViewState`:

```
ViewState["Paging"] = ds;
```

You should **never attempt to put such a big and complex object into ViewState**, because doing so means that a text-based representation of the complex object is created (that is the "serializing" part of the error), and then that huge text is placed in `ViewState` and then sent to the browser(!) which is really unsafe and useless - besides the fact that it generates *so much text* that your application crashes.

If you need to keep a copy of the `DataSet`, either put it into the `Session` object, or use some kind of caching solution such as `HttpContext.Cache`.

Comment: Thanks. i will try to do this